# Bash - Iterate through fmt -w and pass lines to a function

Tags: shell-script

I have a multiline string and I want it first to be formatted to specific length per line before passing each line to a function for line processing.

e.g.

```
description="\
    NOTE: 
    This script should be run on a newly created server. 

    However it can also be re-run selectively even afterwards, to re configure your settings if they were messed up.

    Ready to configure the server for the first time.
"
echo "$description" | fmt -w 80
```

I want to now iterate through the output of the above and send each line to a function.

What I imagine is something like this (which does not work):

```
function testme() {
  for var in "$@"
  do
      echo "$var"
  done
}
echo "$description" | fmt -w 80 | testme
```

Any ideas?

Comment: for starters, maybe you want to reconsider your function name: `test` is a *shell builtin*, and a program at `/usr/bin/test`

Comment: You could get rid of echo and just use here-doc structure. fmt reads stdin with no file specified, so using heredoc should be close enough to a pipe. In fact in some shells, I believe dash, heredoc is implemented as anonymous pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function testme() {
  while IFS='' read line
  do
      echo "$line"
  done
}
echo "$description" | fmt -w 80 | testme
```

Comment: Works but loses the formatting. Can we retain format?

Comment: Similarly but using arguments,

function testme() {
  for var in "$@"
  do
      echo ">>> $var"
  done
}
export -f testme
echo "$description" | fmt -w 80 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c 'testme "$@"' _ {}

This also loses format. But also loses empty lines.

Comment: I've made a little mod: try now

Comment: excellent... How may points can I give you?? )))

Comment: I've made another little, but important mod; now is better: use this one instead.

Comment: Two suggestions: use printf not echo because echo is inconsistent hence portability issue and use read -r do counter backslash escapes. These are very typical if not de facto standard to use in such loop

Comment: `read -r` seems an overkill here, but yeah: it's usually better; `printf` will require to add the `\n`... besides, `echo` without any options (like here) is `POSIX`, so, I think it'll be fine anyways. She/he could decide which is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: echo prints nothing if given the string "-n" or "-e" etc... :(

Comment: obviously, `printf` is superior to `echo`... but that is not the point here: I think that she/he is simply trying to make a quick/dirty bash script to achieve some simple goal, and `printf` would be an overkill for this particular case, and for her/him, it'll be annoying to add the `\n`.